# Handle NodeJS error event?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, event-handling

I have a worker class that has lots of different utility methods, and emits `error` messages when there's a problem anywhere in the execution. Due to NodeJS magic, `error` messages are special, and if nothing is listening to them, they're turned into thrown Errors, so I currently do:

```
var myWorkerFunction = function(input) {
  var w = myFactory();
  try {
    w.dothis();
    w.dothat(input);
    w.hokeypokey();
    return w.finalize();
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

What I wonder though, is it possible to avoid the try/catch block entirely? NodeJS's documentation seems to indicate it's best to avoid not re-throwing a caught exception (I'm doing no checks here to see that it really was my worker's logic that threw the exception and not a critical fault from Node).

So I'd like to do something like:

```
var myWorkerFunction = function(input) {
  var w = myFactory();
  w.on('error', function() {
    // How to tell caller of myWorkerFunction() I failed, 
    //   and stop the rest of the myWorkerFunction function? (return false)
  });
  w.dothis();
  w.dothat(input);
  w.hokeypokey();
  return w.finalize();
}
```

But how to trigger that "return" for `myWorkerFunction` inside that event listener function? I could have `myWorkerFunction` emit an "error" message too, but that just kicks the can to the next layer, and doesn't stop the execution of the worker script (i.e. if `dothis()` fails, don't keep going and call `dothat(input)`). Is there a programming pattern for situations like this?

EDIT: The one solution I could come up with is something like:

```
var myWorkerFunction = function(input) {
  var w = myFactory();
  var hasFailed = false;
  w.on('error', function() {
    hasFailed = true;
  });
  w.dothis();
  if (hasFailed) return fa;se
  w.dothat(input);
  if (hasFailed) return false;
  w.hokeypokey();
  if (hasFailed) return false;
  var out = w.finalize();
  if (hasFailed) return false;
  return out;
}
```

Which is not very elegant having to constantly check if we've failed or not before every line of code.

Comment: You can use domains for this, and then figure out what to do with the error in the callback.

Comment: @adeneo: could you give a code example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple thoughts on this. First you might want to take a look at [Caolan McMahon](https://github.com/caolan)'s fine [async nodejs library](https://github.com/caolan/async) because it feels like you're reinventing flow control that would be handled quite well with 'async.waterfall'.

If you don't feel it's a good fit you - following the pattern you've adopted you could opt to post events on completion of each step (see the 'done' events in the sample below). This would allow you to listen for those events as indication that no error has occurred and that it makes sense to move onto the next step. Let 'finalize' take an optional error to allow your worker to differentiate normal vs abnormal completion. This is not tested but here's what something like that might look like:

```
var myWorkerFunction = function(input) {
  var w = myFactory();
  w.on('error', function(error) {
    // Handle error, log whatever - and finalize with an error?
    w.finalize(error);
  });
  w.on('doneWithThis', function() {
    w.dothat(input);
  });
  w.on('doneWithThat', function() {
    w.hokeypokey();
  });
  w.on('doneWithHokeypokey', function() {
    w.finalize();
  });

  w.dothis(); //starts the ball rolling.
}
```

Comment: Good advice; in the intervening two years since I posted this, I have learned about the `async.waterfall` class, and have used that where I control the library (like this case where the worker methods are mine). As the javascript roadmap is moving towards Promises as a native mechanic, having the worker methods return promises that resolve when done would be another means of doing this.

Comment: @MidnightLightning is it reasonable to mark this as the correct answer?